# Regex two separate nested capturing groups

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have a regex and test case on

https://regex101.com/r/5Z5Lop/1

```
^(?<KEY>CONF|ESD|TRACKING)[:;'\s]\s*(?<DATA>.*?)\s*(?:L[:;'\s]\s*\K(?<LINE_DATA>.*?))?(?<INITIALS>\*[a-zA-Z]+)?\s*$
```

See the `LINE_DATA` named group.

Is it possible to split that group up into two separate groups?

I want one group `LINE_NUMBERS` to hold all integers not contained in parentheses.
Then, 1 group called `QTYS` to hold all integers that are contained in parentheses.

So currently `LINE_NUMBERS` yields `"1,2,3(4),5(12)   "`

Is it possible to have a `LINE_NUMBERS` be `[1,2,3,4]` (either array or some kinda string)
and then `QTYS` to be `[(4),(12)]` Note: I do still want to capture the parentheses.

I would like to do this in the current regex if it's possible and doesn't overly complicate what I currently have.

Right now, I'm obtaining this data through post-processing with separate regexes. I'm using `php`

`preg_match_all('/\d+(?!\s*\))/i', $ret_data['LINE_DATA'], $ret_data['LINE_NUMBERS']);`

Thanks!
`preg_match_all('/\(\s*\d\s*\)/i', $ret_data['LINE_DATA'], $ret_data['QUANTITIES']);`

Comment: It would be a lot easier for readers to understand your question if you stated, at the outset, what you are trying to do, in  words, without any reference to code, and then adding, if you think it helpful to readers, one or more examples for illustration, showing the desired result for each. This is general advice, applying to every question posted to this forum.

Comment: "*Is it possible to split that group up into two separate groups?*" - No, use your current  approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single pattern in the post-processing for the QUANTITIES and the LINE_NUMBERS using an alternation `|` and removing the empty entries from the result.

```
$re = '/^(?<KEY>CONF|ESD|TRACKING)[:;\'\s]\s*(?<DATA>.*?)\s*(?:L[:;\'\s]\s*\K(?<LINE_DATA>.*?))?(?<INITIALS>\*[a-zA-Z]+)?\s*$/i';
$str = 'esd:      here is my data      L:       1,2,3(4),5(12)   *sm          ';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

preg_match_all('/(?<QUANTITIES>\(\d+\))|(?<LINE_NUMBERS>\d+)/', $matches["LINE_DATA"], $numbers);

print_r(array_filter($numbers["QUANTITIES"]));
print_r(array_filter($numbers["LINE_NUMBERS"]));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [3] => (4)
    [5] => (12)
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [4] => 5
)
```

---

There could be an option to use the `\G` anchor to get 2 separate groups for the given example data, but it will make the INITIALS part after it optional:

```
^(?<KEY>CONF|ESD|TRACKING)[:;'\s]\s*(?<DATA>.*?)\s*L[:;'\s]\s*|\G(?!^)(?:(?<QUANTITIES>\(\d+\))|(?<LINE_NUMBERS>\d+)),?(?:\s*(?<INITIALS>\*[a-zA-Z]+)\s*$)?
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?<KEY>CONF|ESD|TRACKING)[:;'\s]\s*` The KEY group with alternatives, and match a single char listed in the character class and optional whitspace chars
- `(?<DATA>.*?)\s*` Match the DATA group, any char non greedy  followed by optional whitespace chars
- `L[:;'\s]\s*` Match `L` the any of the list chars and optional whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<QUANTITIES>\(\d+\))` Group QUANTITIES, match 1+ digits between parenthesis
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<LINE_NUMBERS>\d+)` Group LINE_NUMBERS, match 1+ digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `,?` Match an optional comma
- `(?:\s*(?<INITIALS>\*[a-zA-Z]+)\s*$)?` Optional non capture group with group INITIALS

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EJzZWN/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/o4qYS)